# Paypal sandbox new account email confirmation

Tags: email, paypal

Created 2 new sandbox accounts. Waited for more than 24 hours and never received email with confirmation link. One email was under my domain and another one gmail's. There is nothing wrong in my mailbox receiving mails. Unless I click confirmation link. I couldn't really use sandbox account for testing.

'Contact Us' link in sandbox is taking to to some unrelated error.
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ie/cgi-bin/helpscr?cmd=_help&t=escalateTab

Got a paypal developer account, can it be used for testing?(if sandbox not working)

Answer (score 2):

The PayPal sandbox doesn't send emails to actual accounts.  All the emails that would get sent with a sandbox account are done within your [PayPal developer account](http://developer.paypal.com).

Log in there, then click Dashboard, then click Accounts from the left-side menu.  Then click the little arrow next the account you want to check emails for, and click the Notifications link.  That's where you'll see copies of emails that would be sent for real from a live account.